# Flex overflowing its parent when max-height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have HTML with the following elements:

1. `.modal` - represents page modal and its height is limited to `30vh`.
2. `.wrapper` - represents container that wraps modal content, its content is input (in my app its search input) and list of items.
3. `.list` - list of elements that is wider than `30vh`.

Desired behavior is that wrapper is filled by input, and rest of wrapper is filled by list, if number of items in list is too big scroll should be applied.

For some reason list (and `.wrapper`) overflows the page until I set `display: flex` on `.modal`

Could someone explain to me this behavior? Why does `.wrapper` overflow its parent even though it has `overflow: hidden` and `max-height: 100%` === `30vh` of the parent until `.modal` does not have `display: flex`?

```css
.modal {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-height: 30vh;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input />

    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        sds
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried to add `overflow: scroll` to `.modal`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display flex` to modal or you can limit height of wrapper calc(30vh - 6 rem)

```
.modal {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 30vh;
  height: 100%;
}
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.item {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one line of CSS & remove one.

`overflow-y: auto` to the `.modal`

and

remove `overflow: scroll;` from `.list`

```
.modal {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```